# SwiftUI unwrapping optionals inside View (pyramid of doom)

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a sample program that does three things

> 1. Generate a random integer from -10...10 *(regular function)*
> 2. Generate 10 million random numbers from -10...10 *(asynchronous function)*
> 3. Calculate the average of #2 *(throwing asynchronous function)*

Below is the full working code. It **works without errors**, but the view has a horrible readability with **three nested if/let loops**. What's the best way/convention to get rid of the pyramid of doom in this scenario?

[Result screenshot (how it should work)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XTtx.png)

**Working code** (methods)

```
class NumberManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var integer: Int?
    @Published var numbers: [Double]?
    @Published var average: Double?


    func generateInt() {
        self.integer = Int.random(in: -10...10)
    }
    
    func generateNumbers() async  {
        self.numbers = (1...10_000_000).map { _ in Double.random(in: -10...10) }
        // takes about 5 seconds to run...
    }

    func calculateAverageNumber(for numbers: [Double]) async throws {
        guard !numbers.isEmpty else {
            print("numbers not generated")
            return
        }
        let total = numbers.reduce(0, +)
        let average = total / Double(numbers.count)
        self.average = average
    }
}
```

**Working code** (view)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var numberManager = NumberManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if let integer = numberManager.integer {
            if let numbers = numberManager.numbers {
                if let average = numberManager.average {
                    Text("Integer is \(integer)")
                    Text("First number is: \(numbers[0])")
                    Text("Average is: \(average)")
                } else {
                    LoadingView(loadingType: "Calculating average")
                        .task {
                            do {
                                try await numberManager.calculateAverageNumber(for: numbers)
                            } catch {
                                print("empty numbers array")
                            }
                        }
                }
            } else {
                LoadingView(loadingType: "Generating numbers")
                    .task {
                        await numberManager.generateNumbers()
                    }
            }
        } else {
            LoadingView(loadingType: "Generating int")
                .task {
                    numberManager.generateInt()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**What I tried so far...**
I tried building helper functions to build views as below, and called those functions that returns views inside my ContentView. When I run it, the integer and the number array gets generated and shows, but **the last task that calculates the average does not get called again** at all.

[Result screenshot(with issues)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ59j.png)

**Code** (Runs without errors. But the last task that calculates average doesn't get executed)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var numberManager = NumberManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        intergerView()
            .task {
                print("Generating Int")
                numberManager.generateInt()
            }
        numbersView()
            .task {
                print("Generating Numbers")
                await numberManager.generateNumbers()
            }
        averageView()
            .task {
                do {
                    print("Calculating Average")
                    try await numberManager.calculateAverageNumber(for: numberManager.numbers ?? [])

                } catch {
                    print("error")
                }
            }
    }
}

private func intergerView() -> some View {
    guard let integer = numberManager.integer else {
        return AnyView(LoadingView(loadingType: "Generating int"))
    }
    return AnyView(Text("Integer is \(integer)"))
}

private func numbersView() -> some View {
    guard let numbers = numberManager.numbers else {
        return AnyView(LoadingView(loadingType: "Generating numbers"))
    }
    return AnyView(Text("First number is: \(numbers[0])"))
}

private func averageView() -> some View {
    guard let average = numberManager.average else {
        return AnyView(LoadingView(loadingType: "Calculating average"))
    }
    return AnyView(Text("Average is: \(average)"))
}
```

*EDIT: In my app, I have a view that does all different functions in one view (it's like a dashboard). Some require others to run first (like calculating the average), whereas some can run on its own (Like generating one random integer). I want to display whatever that's loaded first, while displaying a loadingview placeholder for parts that aren't loaded yet.*

Comment: So your app is supposed to do these 3 things one after the other? First generates the int, then the numbers, then the average? How about modelling this using an enum (with associated values representing the integer, numbers, and average) that says which "step" it is doing right now? Then you can have just a switch statement that switches on that enum.

Comment: My app has a view that does all different functions in one view (it's like a dashboard). Some require others to run first (like calculating the average), whereas some can run on its own (Like generating one random integer). I want to display whatever that's loaded first, while displaying a loadingview placeholder for parts that aren't loaded yet.

Comment: Consider putting the if…else logic in your `LoadingView`, so they will display either the loading part or a text based on if the calculation was done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues here:

- `generateNumbers` and `calculateAverageNumber` depend on each other. So they need to await each other.
- your "working code" does not match the description of your code. You say you want to show what ever finishes first but your `if/else` statements introduce dependencies between all 3 functions/views
- you don´t need 3 different views. One that can be customized should be enough.

---

```
class NumberManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var integer: Int?
    @Published var numbers: [Double]?
    @Published var average: Double?
    
    
    func generateInt() {
        self.integer = Int.random(in: -10...10)
    }
    
    func generateNumbers() async  {
        self.numbers = (1...10_000_000).map { _ in Double.random(in: -10...10) }
        // takes about 5 seconds to run...
    }
    
    // No need for arguments here
    func calculateAverageNumber() async throws {
        guard let numbers = numbers, !numbers.isEmpty else {
            print("numbers not generated")
            return
        }
        let total = numbers.reduce(0, +)
        let average = total / Double(numbers.count)
        self.average = average
    }
    
    //This function will handle the dependenies of generating the values and calculating the avarage
    func calculateNumbersAndAvarage() async throws{
        await generateNumbers()
        try await calculateAverageNumber()
    }
}
```

The View:

```
struct ContentView: View{
    
    @StateObject private var numberManager = NumberManager()
    
    var body: some View{
        //Show the different detail views.
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
            
            DetailView(text: numberManager.integer != nil ? "Integer is \(numberManager.integer!)" : nil)
                .onAppear {
                    numberManager.generateInt()
                }
            Spacer()
            Group{
                DetailView(text: isNumbersValid ? "First number is: \(numberManager.numbers![0])" : nil)
                
                Spacer()
                
                DetailView(text: numberManager.average != nil ? "Average is: \(numberManager.average!)" : nil)
            }.onAppear {
                Task{
                    do{
                       try await numberManager.calculateNumbersAndAvarage()
                    }
                    catch{
                        print("error")
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    //Just to make it more readable
    var isNumbersValid: Bool{
        numberManager.numbers != nil && numberManager.numbers?.count != 0
    }
}
```

and the `DetailView`:

```
struct DetailView: View{
    
    let text: String?
    
    var body: some View{
        // If no text to show, show `ProgressView`, or `LoadingView` in your case. You can inject the view directly or use a property for the String argument.
        if let text = text {
            Text(text)
                .font(.headline)
                .padding()
        } else{
            ProgressView()
        }
    }
}
```

---

The code should speak for itself. If you have any further question regarding this code please feel free to do so, but please read and try to understand how this works first.

### Edit:

This does not wait for `calculateAverageNumber` to finish before displaying `numbers[0]`. The reason for it showing at the same time is that it takes almost no time to calculat the avarage. Try adding this between the 2 functions in `calculateNumbersAndAvarage`.

```
try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 4_000_000_000)
```

and you will see that it shows as it should.

Comment: Thank you, it all makes sense. I guess the last piece of the puzzle is, how do I display numbers[0] ahead of average? Yes, calculateAverageNumbes depends on generateNumbers, but not the other way around (generateNumbers can run before calculateAverageNumber). In the code you kindly provided, the view doesn't get updated until average is calculated, even though numbers is generated and updated ahead of that. I tried ungrouping calculateNumbersAndAvarage() task block, and made a separate task block for generateNumbers(), but that view also waits until calculateNumbersAndAvarage() finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done. Use @ViewBuilder , remove AnyView wrapper and dont use guard

```
@ViewBuilder
var intergerView: some View {
    if let integer = numberManager.integer {
        LoadingView(loadingType: "Generating int")
    } else {
        Text("Integer is \(integer)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but no luck - seems like it's basically the same thing as using helper functions (runs without errors, but calculateAverageNumber doesn't execute). I attached a screenshot of what it looks like.